# Present vs. present continuous in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> However, Jane is always forgetting to set her alarm clock, so she often wakes up late. (From Anki)

I know about usage of present and present continuous. To me, this is about habits like regular activity; that is why I thought it was ‘Jane always forgets’ and not ‘Jane is always forgetting’. For instance, we usually use the present form in this sentence: ‘I check my email every day.’ Is the form of this sentence the same? Please, tell me why it isn’t.

Answer (score 1):

The present continuous can be used to express an annoying habit. So the person doesn't approve of Jane waking up late, because she often forgets to set her alarm clock. He finds this annoying, hence the use of the present continuous.

Comment: So the annoying habit is the key, isn’t it?

Comment: yes, this is one of the uses of the present continuous.